# Matching legal move generator

Tags: regex, list, lisp

I have the follwing problem. I have a list of explicit succesorts.

```
(defparameter *tuples*
 '((isa budgie bird) (color budgie yellow)
   (isa tweetie budgie) (color tweetie green)
   (eats budgie seed) (has bird feathers)))
```

So here I create a set of rules:

```
; the explicit successors
(defparameter *tuples2*
 '(((isa ?b bird) => (has ?b feathers))
   ((isa ?b bird) => (has ?b brain))
   ((isa ?b budgie) => (eats ?b seed))
   ((isa ?b budgie) => (color ?b yellow))
   ((isa ?b tweetie) => (color ?b green))
   ((isa ?b tweetie) => (smart ?b small))))
```

1. So in case of tweetie and color required, it should return green,
2. but in case of tweetie and eats should return seed because it
       inherits it from the budgie
3. in case of tweetie and had should return feathers because tweetie
       inherits it from bird.

Example

```
(inherit tuples 'tweetie 'heart-rate) => nil
(inherit tuples 'tweetie 'color)      => green
(inherit tuples 'tweetie 'eats)       => seeds
(inherit tuples 'tweetie 'has)        => feathers
```

I do not know how to retrieve the parent's values.

I have a helper function with a for loop which returns the values for the bird/budgie or tweetie.

```
(defun serve-lmg (state)
  (loop for rule in *tuples*
        when (equal (first rule) state)
        collect (third rule)))
```

so when I run

```
(serve-lmg '(isa ?b bird))
```

I get

```
((HAS ?B FEATHERS) (HAS ?B BRAIN))
```

This is **homework** for me, so I don't expect someone to solve it for me.  I just have been stuck for a while and I don't have progress.  If you could give some help it would be great.  Cheers.

Comment: yeah it seems that I haven't explained to good I will modify it, and we need to use lists for this task.

Comment: Well, it should use single inheritance, no restriction on number of descendants, based on as you said "duck typing" and to be defined by (object;  feature-of-this-type or value)

Comment: "has" has the same usage as "eats" or "color". in case of conflicts like the color it should override it. So if the color is defined in the parent and the child if should use the child value in this example green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here's something that could get you started:

```
(defun is-a (object kind)
  "Object is a singleton class, it is the symbol, which is
also it's own class"
  (or (eql object kind)
      (let ((super (get object :superclass)))
        (and super (is-a super kind)))))

(defun collect-requirements (kind)
  "Collect all features of this class, and all of its superclasses."
  (let ((super (get kind :superclass))
        (present (get kind :features)))
    (if super
        (append present
               (remove-if
                #'(lambda (x)
                    (some #'(lambda (y)
                              (eql (car y) (car x))) present))
                (collect-requirements super)))
        present)))

(defun could-be (object kind)
  "Try to identify an object based on the features it has,
we could know it already as a subclass of `kind', but if
it is not, then try to see if all the requirements of the
`kind' are met in this object."
  (or (is-a object kind)
      (let ((features (get object :features))
            (requirements (collect-requirements kind)))
        (every #'(lambda (x)
                   (some #'(lambda (y)
                             (eql (car y) (car x))) features))
               requirements))))

(defun is-the-same-as (object kind)
  "Very much like `could-be', except it tests for exact
correspondence."
  (or (is-a object kind)
      (let ((features (get object :features))
            (requirements (collect-requirements kind)))
        (every #'(lambda (x) (member x features :test #'equal))
               requirements))))

(defun get-feature (object feature)
  "Looks up a feature in the prototype chain and returns it
if it is there."
  (loop for (n . v) in (collect-requirements object) do
       (when (eql n feature) (return v))))

(defun parse-tuples (tuples)
  "Parses the list of tuples of the form: (feature object subject)
and infers iheritance chain and features of the objects."
  (loop for (feature object subject) in tuples do
       (import feature)
       (import object)
       (if (eql 'isa feature)
           (setf (get object :superclass) subject)
           (setf (get object :features)
                 (cons (cons feature subject)
                       (get object :features))))))

(parse-tuples
 '((isa budgie bird) 
   (color budgie yellow)
   (isa tweetie budgie)
   (color tweetie green)
   (eats budgie seed)
   (has bird feathers)))

(is-a 'budgie 'bird)
(is-a 'budgie 'crocodile)

(get-feature 'budgie 'color)
(get-feature 'tweetie 'color)

(import 'unknown-animal)
(setf (get 'unknown-animal :features)
      '((color . purple) (eats . potatoes) (has . future)))
(is-a 'unknown-animal 'bird)
(could-be 'unknown-animal 'bird)
(could-be 'unknown-animal 'budgie)
(could-be 'unknown-animal 'tweetie)

(import 'more-or-less-a-tweetie)
(setf (get 'more-or-less-a-tweetie :features)
      '((color . green) (eats . seed) (has . feathers)))

(is-the-same-as 'more-or-less-a-tweetie 'tweetie)
(is-the-same-as 'unknown-animal 'tweetie)
```

This describes several kinds possible to build from relationship based on features and direct subclassing. It uses `symbol-plist` as a storage for description for the classes, and it is entirely based on lists (as was your requirement).

What it doesn't do: when it tries to understand the likelihood when using `is-the-same-as` it ignores the fact, that the feature was inherited. I.e. if you give it a new green bird, it will recognize it as possible `tweety`, but will not recognize it as possible `budgie`, otherwise, it will make a very raw guess using the `could-be`.

Comment: Well, I can only be grateful for your time and knoweldge, Cheers mate!